# Displaying a MySQL Table in Real Time in a Webpage

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL table that is constantly being updated, and it has less than 10 rows. Is it possible to display this table in real time in a webpage? I've heard that it can be done using ajax, all the examples I've seen so far are still very confusing. So far I've only managed to display a static table in the webpage using PHP with the following code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>User ID</th>
  <th>Current Location</th>
</tr>
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME','test1');

$link=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if($link===false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect.". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "select * from last_seen";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["user_id"]."</td><td>".$row["location"]."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else{
  echo "0 Results";
}
?>
```

But I haven't found a way to update it in real time without refreshing the page. The table I'm trying to display is like below:

```
user_id  location
-------  --------
1        room1
2        room2
3        room1
```

Comment: First you need a permanent connection between client and server for that, which obviously is out of scope of php. Second you need to be able to _actively_ push changes in the table to the client, which again is nothing a server side solution can deliver. So you definitely do need client side logic. You could use ajax reqeusts and poll, or a long polling strategy or websockets to receive updates from the server when they occur. Then you can update the existing table on the client side.

Comment: Sockets. EventSource. AJAX. There are many ways, each has there pros and cons, you'd rather do research regarding them independently and see which one is best for you.

Comment: just Google about SSE (server send events). Server will send push messages to client .

Answer (score 2):

Why not just append the entered data onto the table with jQuery? That way it will still show what you inserted without the need for wasting bandwidth?

EDIT -

Oh wait, I forgot you'd probably need the ID's for your update/delete actions. I'd suggest putting the logic of that table in a different PHP script, say table.php, and then just refreshing that "container" using an AJAX call to that script?

EDIT #2 -

Sorry, should probably give some example of what I'm talking about.

Say your table is in , I would suggest having a separate PHP script (call it table.php) that actually builds this table for you (I would include this script into the main script for when you load the page initially).

Add the following function to your JS...

```
function getNewTable() {
    $("#data-table").load("table.php");
}
```

After updating your data, call getNewTable(), and that's it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this as Separate Page and call ajax with it,

table_data.php

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>User ID</th>
  <th>Current Location</th>
</tr>
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME','test1');

$link=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if($link===false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect.". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "select * from last_seen";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["user_id"]."</td><td>".$row["location"]."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else{
  echo "0 Results";
}
?>
```

and the main file
index.php

```
<h1>Table Data</h1>
<div id="table_data"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var RefreshTimerInterval = 5000; // every 5 seconds
    $(document).ready(getData);

    function getData() {
        $.get('table_data.php', function(result) {
             $('#table_data').html(result);

             setTimeout(getData, RefreshTimerInterval);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This not good idea nowadays use any UI framework like angular,backbone ... etc